# How to categories rows of a dataframe based on columns on another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am building a dataframe `df` like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'South East Asia': ['India', 'Sri Lanka', 'Mali', 'Maldives'],
    'Europe': ['France', 'Italy', 'Germany', 'Spain'],
    'North America': ['Mexico', 'US', 'Canada', np.nan]},
    columns=['South East Asia', 'Europe', 'North America'])
```

Which looks like this:

```
  South East Asia   Europe North America
0           India   France        Mexico
1       Sri Lanka    Italy            US
2            Mali  Germany        Canada
3        Maldives    Spain           NaN
```

I have a customer data (~40K rows) in another dataframe `df2` with a column `Country` with countries from all the 11 countries listed above.

I want to make a new column in `df2` called Continent which would have the corresponding continent as mentioned in my dataframe `df`. So my desired output for

`print(df2.loc[:, 'Country':'Continent'])`

would be

```
    Country    Continent
0   France        Europe
1    Italy        Europe
2   Mexico    North America
...
```

Note: While looking up this query online, I found that there are some ready-made tools to categories countries into continents, which is understandable since this must be required frequently within the community. But I want to learn how to categorise data based on datasets in another dataframes. That's why I'm trying to achieve the same in only these 11 countries and 3 continents.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dict comprehension with flattening for dictionary:

```
s = {k:v for a, b in df.items() for k, v in dict.fromkeys(b, a).items()}
#if want remove NaNs
#s = {k:v for a, b in df.items() for k, v in dict.fromkeys(b, a).items() if pd.notnull(k)}
```

Or create `Series` with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
s = df.stack().reset_index().set_index(0)['level_1']
print (s)
India        South East Asia
France                Europe
Mexico         North America
Sri Lanka    South East Asia
Italy                 Europe
US             North America
Mali         South East Asia
Germany               Europe
Canada         North America
Maldives     South East Asia
Spain                 Europe
Name: level_1, dtype: object
```

and last [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df2['Continent'] = df2['Country'].map(s)
```

Comment: @Vibhu - In `df2` is no `Country` column? You need `map` column of `df2`

Comment: Hey your code works! I'm sorry for the confusion. Thank you so much for the help my previous questions too. A lot of my `pandas` queries get resolved by your answers on SO

Comment: I tried it with a contact whose country is not included in my dataframe `df` and it got mapped to `NaN`. I wonder how that happened, and if there is a way to set a `default` mapping? @jezrael

Answer (score 1):

Using [`pandas.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.melt.html), you can create a series mapping country to continent:

```
s = pd.melt(df).set_index('value')['variable']

df2['Continent'] = df2['Country'].map(s).fillna('DefaultContinent')
```

For `NaN`, you may want to take extra care. For example:

```
mapper = pd.melt(df).dropna(subset=['value']).set_index('value')['variable']
```

Comment: Thank you @jpp for your answer. Without the `dropna(subset=['value'])`, `Nan` was getting mapped to North America. But when using `mapper` instead of `s`, the `NaN` is dropped as expected. Also for contacts whose countries are not listed in `df`, they are getting mapped to `NaN`. Is there a way to set a _default_ mapping?

Comment: @Vibhu, Sure, that's possible with `pd.Series.fillna`, see upate.